# Uploads DMG file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, dmg

I have an uploader

JS Part:

```
function uploadData(data){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var fData = new FormData();
                for (var k1 in requestData)
                    if (requestData.hasOwnProperty(k1))
                        fData.append(k1, requestData[k1]);
     xhr.open("POST", "ajax/upload", true);
     xhr.send(fData);
}
```

And PHP part:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
file_put_contents(FILES_PATH."/".$_POST['name'], $fileContent);
```

I also have a form on html. After click upload button:

```
var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
var ext = file.name.split(".").pop();
var name = getRandomString(5) + "." + ext;
uploadData({"file": file, "name": name});
```

It works with all files (I tested png, jpg, pdf, doc... mp3) but it doesn't work with .DMG extension. I tested everything. In xhr i used a console and i saw that file exists. When i tried to see `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` or `$_FILES` content i didn't see my .dmg file..

Comment: Isn't the size of your DMG file too big ? Is your script hosted on your own server ? If not, maybe your file is deleted for security reason ...
You can also try to change a pdf file extension by dmg and see what happens.

Comment: @Steven It's right... I had the same problem with PNG extension today. It's strangely. I changed a pdf file extension by dmg and it was uploaded successfully.. It's not mine server. Thanks.

Comment: So, it means that your problem is not (directly) linked to your files extensions. What is the size of your failing uploads ? 
Upload a php file to your server with the following content :  <?php phpinfo(); ?> 
Then, load this page in your browser and search for the value of the  'upload_max_filesize' setting. Make sure the size of the file you are trying to upload is not bigger than this value.